# Historical sovereign bond yield and CDS rate data download

Tags: econometrics, data-request, asset-pricing

Does anyone know where I can download from:

1) historical data for sovereign bond yields (or prices) and 
2) historical data for soveregin CDS (credit default swaps) rates?

preferebly free?

Comment: As you have discovered, CDS data is proprietary, and expensive. As an additional data point, I found no free sources when I looked a few years ago.

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar question in the Quant. Finance section (see here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/22819/where-to-get-price-data-on-credit-default-swaps)

People suggested the following options: https://www.datagrapple.com/ (free for subscription), http://www.markit.com/Product/Pricing-Data-CDS (not free)

I also guess that Bloomberg and Thomson Reuters databases should also contain historical CDS rates. Practicioners use the data source extensively. Though they are very expensive for a personal use, some universities buy a license to get access to it and it is worth asking people from the finance/banking/econ department if they have access to the database.

Answer (score 0):

[FRED](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/) is a good source.

You can find info on both those topics by searching the site.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I agree, FRED is a very good source. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any sovereign CDS data